# Need to get Windows 10 re-installed on laptop with broken Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, windows-10

I bought a Windows 10 laptop from a Dell reseller (harveynorman.com.au) last year. Everything was good until I tried to reboot one day and it got stuck in a boot loop. I tried to automatically repair and that didn't work. I tried to restore to the factory settings, and it consistently freezes at 94.6%.

I'll be starting a new job on Monday which requires that I have a functional laptop running Windows.

What would be the quickest way to get Windows 10 freshly installed on that laptop?

Comment: Download Windows 10 ISO, create installation disk, install Windows 10, Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the laptop is only a year old, the product key should be saved on the motherboard. So you can go to the Microsoft website and use the Windows media creation tool to download a new copy of your version of windows. Use a program like Rufus to put that disc image (ISO file) on a USB stick, I believe you need at least 4GB, then put the USB stick into the laptop that needs the image, then press, I believe it is F12, during the bios screen and select "USB device" in the one time boot option menu. Follow the instructions and like I said the product key should be stored on the motherboard. Unfortunately you will lose all data on the laptop. If there is anything important on there you may want to get that off first.